# overwriting to same log file when using RollingFileAppender in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I'm having problem with log4j. when the log crosses the limit of the file size it's rewriting the existing log instead of creating new one. what can i do to create a new log file after reaching the file size.

```
log4j.appender.Default=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Default.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.Default.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.Default.FilePattern=debug.%i.log
log4j.appender.Default.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Default.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d,%c{1}]%m%n
log4j.appender.Default.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.Default.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.Default.Append=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the files and rotate the log files when it reaches a maximum size by using SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy and defining a rolling policy. Below is a small snippet for your reference,

> log4j.appender.Default.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.Default=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.Default.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
>   log4j.appender.Default.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
>   log4j.appender.Default.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =${log.dir}/${log.file}.log
>   log4j.appender.Default.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log.dir}/${log.file}-.%i.log.gz
>   log4j.appender.Default.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000
>   log4j.appender.Default.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=10

Comment: Is there any other way instead of zip the files?

Comment: You can store it to any format you would need. The configuration is to trigger the rotation and create a new file as and when it has reached the file size.